# Session Login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, session

I have a site `www.example.com` and a wordpress blog at `www.example.com/blog`.

I want my user to login at `www.example.com` and `$_SESSION['USERNAME']` is passed to `www.example.com/blog`.

I just want to know, how can i automatically login the end user to wordpress blog, once they login to my main site.

For now i am passing `$_SESSION['USERNAME']` and using a plugin external database login, which I have linked to my main site database.

Any function that is used to login to wordpress using session username will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress don't use `$_SESSION`you need to code a plugin or to add some code to your functions.php to do this - cf http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress/

You should add something like this :

```
function init_sessions() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_sessions');
```

NB: there is also a plugin to manage Sessions with Wordpress, maybe you can use/hack this http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/

Answer (score 1):

I have been reading on this. Here is what I have found as I am in the same issue. In your wp-config.php file at the top add:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, " The data stored in the session doesn’t go away when the user logs out or logs into a different account. For that you need to destroy the session. ..." [(exerpt from this nice write up)](https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/). It explains you also need to:

```
function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can get wp user_id you could do something like this:

```
function init_sessions() {
    if (user_logged_on_site) {
        @session_start();
        $user_id = $_SESSION['wp_user_id']; //this has to be set when the user logs on your website 

        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id); //log in the user on wordpress
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_sessions');
```

Documentation on wp_set_auth_cookie http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie